# Crystal Report, Cross tab. Value of caculated member

Tags: crystal-reports

Currently have a cross tab and created a calculated member that count 0 values but it doesnt count 0 instead it just count all the records.

already tried to do :

- Create **formula** *If{field} <= 0 Then{field}*

using the **formula created** on the "Edit Value Formula" of Calculated Member

added a COUNT(**formula**) but this display all record count instead the count of data with 0 value within the column.

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmhZV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula that returns 1 for cases you need to count and zero otherwise.
Then, SUM that formula. Note this is SUM -- not COUNT.